# Multiple search in one List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, search

**Try to make search in List**

I'm use this code, but only work the first `.where...`, then the other searches do not happen

List example, I make a get to API, and this is just a very small piece of what comes to me, that's why the search... I need to find it on the list the "ID", the "serviceStatus", the "name" of "unit" and the "name" of "project"

```js
[
  {
    "id": 41,
    "id_technician": "vn97358g8he4g8p9ehg",
    "id_unit": "7fa216b004ed6800c5196ed7",
    "id_project": "3eefc947ae4975eb6375c7",
    "requestDate": "2021-04-16T17:12:24.000Z",
    "dateAttendance": "2021-04-16T17:12:24.000Z",
    "serviceStatus": "novo",
    "customerPaymentStatus": "novo",
    "technicalPaymentStatus": "novo",
    "customerPaymentDate": "2021-04-16T17:12:24.000Z",
    "technicalPaymentDate": "2021-04-16T17:12:24.000Z",
    "checkInTime": "08:00:00",
    "exitTime": "09:00:00",
    "totalOvertime": "00:00:00",
    "totalPayable": "0.00",
    "totalReceivable": "0.00",
    "additionalCharge": "0.00",
    "id_userCreated": "834fd457b31e329e5f59b693",
    "id_userUpdated": "834fd457b31e329e5f59b693",
    "id_advance": null,
    "created_at": "2021-04-16T17:12:24.000Z",
    "update_at": "2021-04-16T17:12:24.000Z",
    "technician": {
      "id": "806a2c33f40619da3b6b401",
      "id_user": "f17ecf1834fd457b31e329e5f59b693",
      "name": "Tecnico Yugi",
      "cpf": "123.123.123-00",
      "rg": "12.123.123-0",
      "address": "av. hora do duelo",
      "cep": "1",
      "state": "sp",
      "city": "sp",
      "district": "loja de cartas",
      "complement": "deck",
      "homeNumber": "123",
      "landline": "11123123123",
      "cellPhone": "11123123123",
      "emergencyName": "Kaiba",
      "emergencyPhone": "11123123123",
      "active": true,
      "mondayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "mondayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "mondayActive": true,
      "tuesdayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "tuesdayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "tuesdayActive": true,
      "wednesdayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "wednesdayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "wednesdayActive": true,
      "thursdayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "thursdayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "thursdayActive": true,
      "fridayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "fridayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "fridayActive": true,
      "saturdayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "saturdayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "saturdayActive": true,
      "sundayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "sundayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "sundayActive": true,
      "id_technicalType": "19368d796535e48abc13857",
      "id_agent": null,
      "created_at": "2021-04-16T17:11:16.000Z",
      "update_at": "2021-04-29T17:04:17.000Z"
    },
    "unit": {
      "id": "7f3eca21-6b00-4ed6-b800-c5196efd05d7",
      "name": "Kaiba CORP",
      "companyName": "",
      "ced": "",
      "address": "uma rua la",
      "id_flag": "90191715d1bb20f14f",
      "cnpj": "123123123213 ",
      "cep": "12412412 ",
      "number": "141 ",
      "responsibleName": "User Exemple ",
      "telephoneResponsible": "124124 ",
      "state": " Exemple ",
      "city": " Exemple ",
      "district": " Exemple ",
      "complement": " Exemple ",
      "landline": "123123123123 ",
      "active": false,
      "mondayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "mondayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "mondayActive": false,
      "tuesdayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "tuesdayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "tuesdayActive": false,
      "wednesdayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "wednesdayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "wednesdayActive": false,
      "thursdayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "thursdayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "thursdayActive": false,
      "fridayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "fridayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "fridayActive": false,
      "saturdayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "saturdayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "saturdayActive": false,
      "sundayEntryTime": "08:00:00",
      "sundayDepartureTime": "17:00:00",
      "sundayActive": false,
      "created_at": "2021-04-13T15:34:29.000Z",
      "update_at": "2021-04-13T15:34:29.000Z",
      "flag": {
        "id": "90197171-05d8-4147-bb73-ee386a20f14f",
        "name": "Jaiden",
        "id_businessGroup": "246asd112c79fcbed0e1ddc",
        "description": "abc",

"active": true,
        "created_at": "2021-04-13T15:34:13.000Z",
        "update_at": "2021-04-14T18:29:17.000Z",
        "businessGroup": {
          "id": "24611216-6c79-44e9-9f8b-bcbed0ea1ddc",
          "name": "Monstros de Duelo",
          "id_client": "9cd756d431ca3f85f746552ebd",
          "description": "abc",
          "active": true,
          "created_at": "2021-04-12T21:38:51.000Z",
          "update_at": "2021-04-13T17:48:38.000Z",
          "client": {
            "id": "9cd75033-36d0-431c-a3f3-85f746552ebd",
            "name": "Mago Negro",
            "address": "Rua tal",
            "companyName": "Empresa Com nome",
            "cnpj": "15.646.546/5465-46",
            "cep": "46465-456",
            "number": "",
            "responsibleName": "Maximillion",
            "telephoneResponsible": "(56) 5 4654-5465",
            "state": "jp",
            "city": "uma cidade",
            "district": "um bairro",
            "complement": "full",
            "landline": "(45) 6465-4654",
            "cellPhone": "(56) 4 5645-4654",
            "active": false,
            "created_at": "2021-04-12T17:24:50.000Z",
            "update_at": "2021-04-12T17:24:50.000Z"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "project": {
      "id": "3eefc3bc-7947-4ab7-ae44-d975eb6375c7",
      "name": "Duel Monsters",
      "chargeHourlyOfProject": "15:00:00",
      "valueTechnician": "60.00",
      "valueClient": "210.00",
      "valueHourExtraTechnician": "70.00",
      "valueHourExtraClient": "110.00",
      "description": "Comprar a Kaiba CORP",
      "active": true,
      "created_at": "2021-03-25T20:20:44.000Z",
      "update_at": "2021-04-22T18:46:43.000Z"
    },
    "invoice_url": null
  }
]
```

Sorry, I try to make the code easy to read, but I can't add the **bold** to a `[{code}]`

```dart
@computed
  List get resultadoBusca {
    if (buscar.isEmpty) {
      return listaOSs;
    } else {
      return listaOSs
          .where((e) => e["project"]["name"]
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(buscar.toLowerCase()))
          .toList()
            ..where(
                (e) => e["unit"]["name"]
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(buscar.toLowerCase())).toList()
            ..where((e) => e["serviceStatus"]
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(buscar.toLowerCase())).toList();
    }
  }
```

I try this

```dart
    listaOSs.where((e) {
        return e["project"]["name"]
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(buscar.toLowerCase()) &&
            e["unit"]["name"].contains(buscar.toLowerCase()) &&
            e["serviceStatus"].toLowerCase().contains(buscar.toLowerCase());
      }).toList();
```

and this

```dart
    listaOSs
          .where((e) =>
              e["project"]["name"].toLowerCase().contains(buscar.toLowerCase()))
          .where((e) =>
              e["unit"]["name"].toLowerCase().contains(buscar.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
```

None works, with 1 `.where` in return works, but i'm need make cascade, similar with this

```js
    const filter = rows.filter(
      (row) => {
        const searchText = normalizedText(filterText).toLowerCase();

        return (
          normalizedText(row.name)?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
          || normalizedText(row.state)?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
          || normalizedText(row.city)?.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Why did you write `..where`? It isn't needed in this case. Try writing `.where`, with only one dot.

Comment: @Andrej i'm try to run in cascade the search... With one dot have dead code

Comment: The expression `x..y` evaluates to `x`.  By using `x..where()`, you are throwing away the result of `where()`.

Comment: Additionally, you don't need to call `.toList()` at each intermediate step.  You can just do: `listaOSs.where(...).where(...).where(...).toList()`.  Furthermore, it also would be a bit simpler to combine them: `listaOSs.where((e) { var buscarLower = buscar.toLowerCase(); return e['project']['name'].toLowerCase().contains(buscarLower) && e['unit']['name'].contains(buscarLower) && e['serviceStatus'].toLowerCase().contains(buscarLower); }).toList()`.

Comment: `void main() {
  final List lst = [
    {'a': true, 'b': false},
    {'a': true, 'b': false},
    {'a': true, 'b': true},
  ];

  print(lst.where((e) => e['a'] == true).where((e) => e['b'] == false));
}
` If you put `..` in front of `where` this code doesn't work, however if you put only one it works perfectly. That is the problem with your code.

Comment: @jamesdlin I try your suggestion, but don't work :/ 

```
listaOSs.where((e) {
        return e["project"]["name"]
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(buscar.toLowerCase()) &&
            e["unit"]["name"].contains(buscar.toLowerCase()) &&
            e["serviceStatus"].toLowerCase().contains(buscar.toLowerCase());
      }).toList();``` 

but thanks to try, my code must have some error

Comment: @Andrej itry to use onde dot, but don't work :/

```listaOSs
          .where((e) =>
              e["project"]["name"].toLowerCase().contains(buscar.toLowerCase()))
          .where((e) =>
              e["unit"]["name"].toLowerCase().contains(buscar.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    ```

thanks for try, my code must have some error

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's some chance that the process of creating an example is enough that you understand what's going wrong. In any case, it makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: @Christian her, it's work ```String buscar = "";```, ```void setBuscando(String value) => buscar = value;``` and ```List get resultadoBusca {
    
    if (buscar.isEmpty) {
      return listaOSs;
    } else {
      return listaOSs
          .where((e) =>
              e["project"]["name"].toLowerCase().contains(buscar.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }
  }``` this is the search i'm using, but with only 1 method

Comment: I think that you don't need the `.toList()` either.

Comment: @Andrej if i remove the ```.toList()``` a receive this error "A value of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' can't be returned from the function 'resultadoBusca' because it has a return type of 'List<dynamic>'."